# Fragment con drawermenu en el action toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-drawerlayout

El problema es el siguiente tengo mi main activiy que se compone de un drawer `activity` cuando le doy a alguna de la opciones del drawer activity tengo que pase a un `fragment` , el problema es el siguiente cuando paso al `fragment` pierdo la opción de abrir el menú del drawer desde el `fragment`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_trigonometria) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cont, new Fragmen1()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_conversor) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cont, new Fragmen2()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

ese es el código java del `main activity`

este es el código del `fragment` donde quiero implementar el `drawer`

```
public class Fragmen1 extends Fragment {
    Button HBoton;
    Button GBoton;
    Button SCTBoton;
    Button RGboton;
    Button CPBoton;
    Button ARBoton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmen1, container, false);

        HBoton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.HipotenusaBoton);

        HBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent HBoton = new Intent(getActivity(), Hipotenusa.class);
                startActivity(HBoton);
            }
        });

        GBoton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        GBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent GBoton = new Intent(getActivity(), Grados_Radianes.class);
                startActivity(GBoton);
            }
        });

        SCTBoton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.SCTboton);

        SCTBoton.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public  void  onClick (View v ) {
                Intent SCTBoton = new Intent(getActivity(), SenoCosenoTangente.class);
                startActivity(SCTBoton);
            }
        });

        RGboton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button6);

        RGboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent RGboton = new Intent(getActivity(),RadianesGrados.class);
                startActivity(RGboton);
            }
        });

        CPBoton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.CAPbutton);

        CPBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent CPBoton = new Intent( getActivity(),CordenadasRectagularesPolares.class);
                startActivity(CPBoton);
            }
        });

        ARBoton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.arboton);

        ARBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent ARBoton = new Intent( getActivity(),AnguloReferencia.class);
                startActivity(ARBoton);
            }
        });

        return  view;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "este es el codigo del fragment donde quiero implementar el drawer"

El `NavigationDrawer` debe estar generalmente en la Activity que contiene los Fragmentos, esto para solo reemplazar el contenido.

En el caso que no desees el Navigation Drawer en algún Fragmento, simplemente al realizar la transacción de este,  deshabilitas el `Navigation Drawer`.

Comment: Ahi estoy utilizando el activity que genera android studio por defecto , pero cuando creo un fragment para una opcion del NavigationDrawer , cuando estoy en esa opcion en la pantalla pierdo la capacidad de abrir el NavigationDrawer desde esa localizacion